# How can I improve the speed of this for loop code?

Tags: r

How can I improve the speed of this for loop code?

```
y<-data.frame(f1=round(runif(100, 1,5)),
              f2=round(runif(100, 1,5)),
              f3=round(runif(100, 1,5)))
m <- nrow(y)
nr <- rownames(y) 
response <- matrix(NA, m, m, dimnames=list(nr, nr))
for(a in 1:m) for(b in 1:m) 
  response[a, b] <- all(y[a,]<=y[b,])
response
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve, and what is your desired output

Answer (score 2):

Convert `y` to matrix and you can use `apply` functions to improve speed.

```
dat = as.matrix(y)
response2 = sapply(1:m, function(i) apply(dat, 1, function(x) all(x <= dat[i,])))
dimnames(response2) = list(nr, nr)
```

Benchmarking

```
y<-data.frame(f1=round(runif(20, 1,5)),
              f2=round(runif(20, 1,5)),
              f3=round(runif(20, 1,5)))
m <- nrow(y)
nr <- rownames(y) 

microbenchmark(f1 = {
    response <- matrix(NA, m, m, dimnames=list(nr, nr))
    for(a in 1:m) for(b in 1:m) 
        response[a, b] <- all(y[a,]<=y[b,])
},
f2 = {
    dat = as.matrix(y)
    response2 = sapply(1:m, function(i) apply(dat, 1, function(x) all(x <= dat[i,])))
    dimnames(response2) = list(nr, nr)
})
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq      max neval
#    f1 73.3571 77.43730 84.701259 79.64565 85.7293 135.9448   100
#    f2  1.9453  2.16485  2.544873  2.27505  2.5295   5.9237   100
identical(response, response2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: response2 is not identical to response, sorry

Comment: Great! This is a very good improvement! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @d.b that converting the data to a matrix is the best first step, but using the matrixStats package you can also avoid the nested loops.

```
y<-data.frame(f1=round(runif(100, 1,5)),
              f2=round(runif(100, 1,5)),
              f3=round(runif(100, 1,5)))
m <- nrow(y)
nr <- rownames(y) 

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1 = {
  response <- matrix(NA, m, m, dimnames=list(nr, nr))
  for(a in 1:m) for(b in 1:m) 
    response[a, b] <- all(y[a,]<=y[b,])
},
f2 = {
  dat = as.matrix(y)
  response2 = sapply(1:m, function(i) apply(dat, 1, function(x) all(x <= dat[i,])))
},
f3 = {
  response3 <- matrix(NA, m, m, dimnames=list(nr, nr))
  z <- as.matrix(y)
  for (i in 1:m) {
    response3[i,] <- matrixStats::rowAlls(matrix(rep(z[i, ], m), nrow = m, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) <= z)  
  }
  
})
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min         lq        mean     median         uq       max neval
   f1 1154.2246 1164.34475 1178.059824 1170.31180 1177.58840 1272.3578   100
   f2   24.4325   25.09795   27.147773   26.13300   29.82185   32.7160   100
   f3    3.6844    3.94145    4.104324    4.04175    4.13685    9.7601   100
```

```
identical(response, response3)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! f3 was that I wanted to find !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `outer` like below

```
lst <- asplit(y, 1)
outer(lst, lst, FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y) all(x <= y)))
```

Comment: Thank you @ThomasIsCoding but "outer" is slow with a big amount of data.

Comment: @LuigiBiagini yes, you are right, it would be slow with a big amount of data